# Run custom application in openshift next gen

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I recently got into the Openshift Next Gen preview and wanted to start running an application there. I would like to use http://luvit.io to run my application, but it's not listed in the base images when creating an application. 
I then tried to use the oc cli with a custom docker hub dockerfile but that gave me an error saying that the docker build type is now allowed. 
I couldn't find any good documentation on how to run my own application on openshift next gen, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: So as far as I understand you have a dockerfile of your app and you want to build the image and run inside openshift-origin (which version? 1.3?).

Comment: I'm in the OpenShift Online (Next Gen) Developer Preview thingy and want to run an application that isn't one of the prebuilt ones. So yes I basically only have a dockerfile that downloads and compiles some binary and a github repo with some code that binary should run.

Answer (score 0):

If you host your Docker image on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/), you can run it straightforwardly, check this article:
https://blog.openshift.com/deploying-images-from-dockerhub

Your image must be public and not run as root.

I confess i still have problems with ip bindings for my services, but i think it's a good start.